# Existe um efeito Parallax Mousemove para jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como encontro um efeito do tipo "*[parallax mousemove](http://wagerfield.github.io/parallax/)*"

Gostaria de saber o nome desse efeito e se tem algum exemplo na internet.

Eu sabia fazer esse efeito em ActionScript 3.0 se chamava `Scrollrect`, mas não sei o nome correto em jQuery.

Comment: No próprio link que você já, clicando no "i", tem um link para o github do projeto, lá você pode consultar o código-fonte. Esse tipo de efeito se chama "parallax" mesmo.

Comment: obrigado pela dica mas ja tentei com esse código que eles deixaram, mas não consegui fazer o que eu queria, que é deixar o background com efeito mouse move , vc não sabe algum outro exemplo semelhante na internet não, agradeço desde já...

Comment: Faça uma busca por [jquery parallax](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+parallax&oq=jquery+parallax&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8), tem vários. Não saberia recomendar um pois nunca usei nenhum.

Comment: Você pode tentar usar [esse plugin do jQuery](http://stephband.info/jparallax/).
O site possui algumas instruções, lista de sites com demonstrações e sites comerciais que utilizam jparallax.

Comment: Provavelmente o que você procura esta [nesse site](http://stephband.info/jparallax/)

Comment: [Esse aqui](http://wagerfield.github.io/parallax/) é muito melhor. Funciona perfeitamente no iPhone e no iPad. Faz o <i>parallax</i> inclinando o aparelho.

Answer (score 6):

## [Parallax](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paralaxe)

*Em Português pode aparecer escrito "Paralaxe".*

> Paralaxe vem do Grego: παραλλαγή que significa alteração. É a alteração da posição angular de dois pontos estacionários relativos um ao outro como vistos por um observador em movimento. De forma simples, paralaxe é a alteração aparente de um objeto contra um fundo devido ao movimento do observador.

Numa página de internet, a deslocação do ponto de vista do utilizador é simulada através da movimentação do rato.

Qualquer projecto que se refira a *Parallax* está efectivamente a construir um efeito de deslocação de objectos com base na movimentação do rato.

## [jquery.parallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/)

[image: Imagem ilustrativa]

Esta página é um bom exemplo de um dos primeiros projectos de *Parallax* onde podes obter uma explicação de como tudo funciona e observar alguns exemplos de utilização.

Fazendo uso de uma colecção de elementos, na imagem em cima são `li`, onde cada uma é camada de efeito para simular a alteração do ponto de visão do utilizador obtido através da deslocação do rato.

#### Exemplo de utilização:

[Demonstração a funcionar](http://stephband.info/jparallax/demos/index.html)

Assumindo que as camadas estão construídas da seguinte forma:

**HTML**

```html
<div id="port">
 <!-- 7 Camadas de imagens, cada camada ligeiramente maior que a que se encontra por trás -->
 <img class="parallax-layer" src="../images/parallax_drops/0.png" alt=""/>
 <img class="parallax-layer" src="../images/parallax_drops/1.png" alt=""/>
 <img class="parallax-layer" src="../images/parallax_drops/2.png" alt=""/>
 <img class="parallax-layer" src="../images/parallax_drops/3.png" alt=""/>
 <img class="parallax-layer" src="../images/parallax_drops/4.png" alt=""/>
 <img class="parallax-layer" src="../images/parallax_drops/5.png" alt=""/>
 <img class="parallax-layer" src="../images/parallax_drops/6.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  // Declarar o efeito nas camadas
  jQuery('.parallax-layer').parallax({
    mouseport: jQuery("#port")          // indicar o elemento que envolve o efeito
  });
});
```

Irias obter algo deste género que pode ser visto no link para a demonstração:

[image: Captura de Tela]

E deslocando o rato para baixo existe a referida alteração do ponto de visão dando ideia que o utilizador de abaixou:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Answer (score 0):

Eu conheço este componente de JavaScript chamado [Panorama](http://www.jsclasses.org/package/56-JavaScript-Display-layers-that-can-scroll-at-different-speeds.html) que produz o efeito que descreve, mas faz a rolagem dos elementos na página na horizontal.

Este componente permite definir diversas camadas que se movem a velocidades diferentes como se estivessem a distâncias diferentes do ponto de vista do usuário, dando a sensação de vista panorâmica, e daí o nome.

Note, eu modero o site onde está esse componente, mas não sou o autor do mesmo.