# Como fazer o efeito paralax na horizontal e vertical ao mesmo tempo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como fazer com o efeito paralax que existe no seguinte site:
http://hellomonday.com/

Na setas no lado esquerdo (seta para cima), após o site carregar, veja o exemplo do planeta terra.

Como fazer esse efeito com javascript ou algum plugin pré-feito?

Procuro por paralax mas não encontro.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3218/129 e aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23584/129

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você quis dizer estrutura de apresentação, se for isso tem esse framework [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/)